# Rsync --exclude-from= query on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: rsync

I am trying to backup my home folder to an external drive with the following command:

```
rsync -acu --delete --exclude-from='/home/chh1/rsync_exclude.txt' /home/ /media/chh1/f86f92f7-bcb4-4b8e-8a64-8a210606d422/home_backup/
```

The --exclude-from= file

```
/home/chh1/rsync_exclude.txt
```

contains the following entries:

```
.cache
crewdb.bak.sql
```

I really want to exlude .cache but also .dconf which is contained within it as I want to exclude files that require root privileges and unnecessary .cache data contained in /home/chh1/.cache.

When I run

```
find ~ -name ".cache"
```

I get the following output:

```
/home/chh1/snap/pdfmixtool/common/.cache
/home/chh1/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache
/home/chh1/snap/okular/63/.cache
/home/chh1/snap/freemind/common/.cache
/home/chh1/.cache
find: ‘/home/chh1/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
```

I really want to exclude

```
/home/chh1/.cache
```

which would take care of dconf and general .cache junk as well. However, I do not want to exclude the other .cache directories found when running the find command.

since --exclude-from= only matches patterns with what is in the exclude file, how can I specify a path rather than a pattern and preferably within the exclude file? Is there a way?

Thanks for your help it is indeed much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exclude list can have absolute names too, that match beneath the starting directory, `/home/` in your case. Use the line

```
/chh1/.cache
```

instead of `.cache` to only exclude `/home/` `/chh1/.cache`, i.e. `/home/chh1/.cache`

Comment: Thanks meuh, that has solved the problem!